# How to parse musixmatch python api JSON response?

Tags: python, json, api, musixmatch

How do you parse the JSON response from the musixmatch api?
I'm calling the method 
res = artist_api.artist_search_get(format=format, q_artist=artist)

I'm getting a response of

```
{'message': {'body': {'artist_list': [{'artist': {'artist_alias_list': [],
                                                  'artist_comment': '',
                                                  'artist_country': '',
                                                  'artist_credits': {'artist_list': []},
                                                  'artist_edit_url': None,
                                                  'artist_id': 26575484.0,
                                                  'artist_mbid': None,
                                                  'artist_name': 'Illenium',
                                                  'artist_name_translation_list': [],
                                                  'artist_rating': 55.0, .........
```

I'm trying to get the artist_id.

I tried getting the artist_id like this:

```
    print(res['message']['body']['artist']['artist_id'])
```

```
artist_api = swagger_client.ArtistApi()
format = 'json' 

try:
    artist_list = ["adele", "lady gaga", "john legend"];
    for artist in artist_list:
        print(artist)
        res = artist_api.artist_search_get(format=format, q_artist=artist)
        print(res['message']['body']['artist']['artist_id'])
except ApiException as e:
    print "Exception when calling ArtistApi->artist_search_get: %s\n" % e
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "musixmatch.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(res['message']['body']['artist_id'])
TypeError: 'InlineResponse2004' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Please help I've searched through a bunch of threads but I still can't find the answer to this. I'm new to python so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a little messed up with the hierarchy of JSON-document, use this code to get desired values:

```py
[artist['artist']['artist_id'] for artist in res['message']['body']['artist_list']]
```

As an alternative, can be used [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)-expression: `$..artist_list..artist_id` to get the same result.

**Example**

```py
from jsonpath_rw import parse
import json

res = json.loads("""{
  "message": {
    "header": {},
    "body": {
      "artist_list": [
        {
          "artist": {
            "artist_credits": {            },
            "artist_country": "string",
            "artist_id": 110
          }
        },
        {
          "artist": {
            "artist_credits": {},
            "artist_country": "string",
            "artist_id": 220
          }
        }        
      ]
    }
  }
}""")

# 1-way: Iterate through JSON-document
print([artist['artist']['artist_id'] for artist in res['message']['body']['artist_list']])
# result: [110, 220]

# 2-way: Use JSONPath-expression
jsonpath_expr = parse('$..artist_list..artist_id')
print([match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(res)])
# result: [110, 220]
```